# How to switch sprite between differents CCSpriteBatchNode in cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm making a game in cocos2d, I have a chicken as character  that use a CCSprite. This chicken have multiple images doing different movements.

There are so many images for the movements that I have to use multiple plist files for the sprite.

My problem is that I can switch between the differents sprites

```
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
     @"chicken-1to3.plist"];

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
     @"chicken-4to5.plist"];

    spriteSheet1to3 = [CCSpriteBatchNode
                                      batchNodeWithFile:@"chicken-1to3.png"];
    spriteSheet4to5 = [CCSpriteBatchNode
                                      batchNodeWithFile:@"chicken-4to5.png"];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet1to3 z:1];
    [self addChild:spriteSheet4to5 z:2];

    NSMutableArray *chickenManAni1Imgs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *chickenManAni2Imgs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *chickenManAni3Imgs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *chickenManAni4Imgs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *chickenManAni5Imgs = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i) {
        [chickenManAni1Imgs addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chicken-1-%d.png", i]]];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 19; ++i) {
        [chickenManAni2Imgs addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chicken-2-%d.png", i]]];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 21; ++i) {
        [chickenManAni3Imgs addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chicken-3-%d.png", i]]];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 16; ++i) {
        [chickenManAni4Imgs addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chicken-4-%d.png", i]]];
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= 36; ++i) {
        [chickenManAni5Imgs addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"chicken-5-%d.png", i]]];
    }

    chickenManAni1 = [CCAnimation
                   animationWithSpriteFrames:chickenManAni1Imgs delay:0.04f];
    chickenManAni2 = [CCAnimation
                      animationWithSpriteFrames:chickenManAni2Imgs delay:0.04f];
    chickenManAni3 = [CCAnimation
                      animationWithSpriteFrames:chickenManAni3Imgs delay:0.04f];
    chickenManAni4 = [CCAnimation
                      animationWithSpriteFrames:chickenManAni4Imgs delay:0.04f];
    chickenManAni5 = [CCAnimation
                      animationWithSpriteFrames:chickenManAni5Imgs delay:0.04f];

    chickenMan = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"chicken-5-1.png"];
    chickenMan.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);

    [spriteSheet4to5 addChild:chickenMan];

    [chickenMan runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                          [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:chickenManAni5 restoreOriginalFrame:NO]]];
    chickenManAniRunning = 1;
```

Here is the code when I try to change the sprite

```
        [chickenMan stopAllActions];
        [spriteSheet4to5 removeChild:chickenMan cleanup:YES];
        [spriteSheet1to3 addChild:chickenMan];

        [chickenMan runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                               [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:chickenManAni2 restoreOriginalFrame:NO]]];
```

After that I get this error: 
**'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'**

**UPDATE**: I'm using two differents sprites:

```
    chickenMan1to3 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"chicken-1-1.png"];
    chickenMan1to3.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [chickenMan1to3 setVisible:YES];

    chickenMan4to5 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"chicken-5-1.png"];
    chickenMan4to5.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [chickenMan4to5 setVisible:NO];
```

And I switch them this way:

```
        [chickenMan1to3 stopAllActions];
        [chickenMan1to3 setVisible:NO];
        [chickenMan4to5 setVisible:YES];
        [chickenMan4to5 runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                                   [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:chickenManAni4 restoreOriginalFrame:NO]]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use two sprites, one for each batch node. When switching to anim from the other batch node, set the animating sprite visible and hide the other. To make them animate in synch add both sprites to a ccnode which will then represent your chicken character as far as position, actions and other logic is concerned.

If the chicken is the only sprite child in the batch node you can simply remove the batch node since batching is only helping when you have muliple instances of the same sprite and texture.

Comment: LearnCocos2D, thank you very much!, Now I have a happy dancing chicken. When you said "remove the batch node", You mind to delete the line "[self addChild:spriteSheet1to3 z:1];" and use "[self addChild:chickenMan1to3];"?

Comment: And also delete "CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile".

Comment: Yes, no sprite batch node at all. Provided that each batch node only has that one children it's just going to get in the way.